# cannot echoing result from table

Tags: php, database, pdo

I can echo `$row_count` but I am unable to print `$first`.

Account table contain `fname` and `lname`.

Can anyone fix this problem?

```
public function getAccountInfoAll(){
        $acc_info = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM account");
        $results = $acc_info->fetchAll();
        $row_count = $acc_info->rowCount();
        echo $row_count.' rows selected';
        while ($row = $acc_info->fetchAll()) 
          {
          $first = $row['fname'];
          echo $first;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public function getAccountInfoAll(){
    $acc_info = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM account");
    $acc_info->execute();

    $row_count = $acc_info->rowCount();
    echo $row_count.' rows selected';

    while ($row = $acc_info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $first = $row['fname'];
      echo $first;
    }        
}
```

[More information on prepared statements.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your using PDO, so here's what you did wrong :

```
$acc_info = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM account");
$acc_info->execute();
$results = $acc_info->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row_count = $acc_info->rowCount();
echo $row_count.' rows selected';
foreach($results AS $row) {
   $first = $row['fname'];
   echo $first.'<br />';
}
```